# Select string of text minus text in parentheses

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of account names like this, the column name is *location_description*:

```
BOULDER COMM FTHLLS HOSP (021171)
DELTA MEMORIAL HOSPITAL (019991)
DENVER HEALTH MEDICAL CTR (013500)
```

I am using postgres and need to Select these items but remove the parentheses and numbers inside them. Final would look like this:

```
BOULDER COMM FTHLLS HOSP
DELTA MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
DENVER HEALTH MEDICAL CTR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regexp_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) for that

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '\s*\([0-9]+\)', '')
from the_table;
```

The regex matches for any string that starts with a `(` is followed by at least one number and then is followed by a `)`. The `\s*` is there to also remove the (white)space before the `(`

If the text between the parentheses can contain other characters (which your sample data doesn't) then you can extend the `[0-9]` part to include additional characters, e.g. `[0-9-]` to also include a dash.